# Filter on a Multivalues field in aggegations

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

I got an entity like this:

```
{
   id: "id1",
   values: [0, 1, 5, 20, 30]
}
```

The values array contains a high number of values (up to 100k) which are actually dates (For easier use I took ints here). So I need to extract all dates in a range over several documents. I need the union of values of all documents matching some criteria.

Currently I have a query and a terms aggregation to get all the values. But I need to have the values filtered in ranges. Is it possible to tell the aggregation to just take values between 10 and 20 even though the document in question has values from 1-100k in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done but it will be tricky in your case. For numeric values like in your example, you could [filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_filtering_values_2) them by providing them in an array.

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "unique": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "date_values",
        "size": 10,
        "include": [10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

but since you have dates, you would have to index them in separate field as **string** with **index:not_analyzed**. You could use [copy_to](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/copy-to.html) for that if you want. After that you would need **regex** to filter range of dates.

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "unique": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "string_date_values",
        "size": 10,
        "include": "2016.*|2015.*"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The above query will give you only dates that start with 2016 OR 2015 like *2016-04-04*, *2015-11-10* etc.

Comment: Though I ended up just Filtering on another side because this is even more tedious it could be helpful :)